# PHP getting error : File not found atfer setting header('charset=utf-8');

Tags: php, character-encoding

Good day,

After setting PHP `header('charset=utf-8');`
I receive the following error :

```
File not found

An error occurred during a connection to example.com.

    Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

This only occurs on my Unix server. Whilst on my Wamp Developement environment everything is just find.
I hope I am overlooking a critical element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the content-type, like so:

```
header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');
```